# How use multiple Artifacts in Release Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am using 3 CI Pipeline which mapping into one Release Pipeline, on each CI Pipeline created some artifacts. In running process of release pipeline some artefacts can are update (other CI pipeline was run), and i want use update version.

Comment: Can you add a bit more on your problem? I need more information in order to help you with a proper response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In running process of release pipeline use update version of artifacts.

I'm afraid what you want is not supported yet cause Azure Devops Service doesn't support to change the artifacts version after the release  is created.

Here is a doc about [the release artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/artifacts?view=azure-devops):

> After a release is created, you cannot change these versions. A
>   release is fundamentally defined by the versioned artifacts that make
>   up the release. As you deploy the release to various stages, you will
>   be deploying and validating the same artifacts in all stages.

If you want to use the latest version of artifacts, you need to create a new release.

You could add your request for this feature on our [UserVoice site](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21), this is our main forum for product suggestions. Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps.